# To invite or inviting

Tags: grammar

> Dean Sir recommended to invite the above-distinguished dignitaries.

or

> Dean sir recommended inviting the above-distinguished dignitaries.

I am getting confused. Most people use the first sentence. However, spell and grammar check tools suggest the opposite. Would you be kind enough to clear my doubt?

Note: Is it inviting or to invite?

Comment: Can you check you sentences carefully please? What does “dean sir” mean?

Comment: Dean is a post in Universities.

Comment: We know what a dean is, not a Dean Sir. *Inviting* works better than *to invite* does, and the rest needs work to be clear. *Above-mentioned distinguished* may be what you had in mind rather than above-distinguished.

Comment: What in the world is an "above-distingished" anything? That is not English.

Comment: @tchrist [“It is by the latter of these names the above distinguished warrior is best known”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UKZlAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA687&lpg=PA687&dq=above+distinguished&source=bl&ots=Zq4fwM1AHU&sig=ACfU3U2TfDDZSZ6xjy-9AQiGYmJLJXDntA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9-Zb1r9fnAhXXQkEAHRnXBRsQ6AEwE3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=above%20distinguished&f=false). Though the usage is quite old.

Comment: @aesking Nope, that doesn't have a hyphen. Completely different.

Comment: @tchrist not all compound lexis need a hyphen...

Answer (score 1):

There is some variability. But I would say that *recommend* takes either:

> a "that" clause: *He recommend that I invite...*

or

> an "- ing" clause (usually without the subject expressed): *He recommended inviting ...*

A "to" infinitive clause doesn't sound right to me, though I have no doubt that some people say it. I suspect that they are mostly not native English speakers.

Note again that this is an accidental feature of the English lexicon, and is not predictable from meaning. So, for example, *advise* **can** take a "to" clause: *He advised me to invite ...*